# Can't Figure Out How To Fix Memory Leaks on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

I was running Leaks tool and discovered a massive leak in my Dictionary mutableDeepCopy but I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. Any suggestions?

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController{

  NSDictionary *immutableDictionary;
  NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary;
}
```

Here is the line of code that's highlighted in Instruments

```
self.mutableDictionary = [self.immutableDictionary mutableDeepCopy];
```

Here is the method for creating a mutable copy of a Dictionary

```
@interface NSDictionary(MutableDeepCopy)
  -(NSMutableDictionary *)mutableDeepCopy;
@end
```

Here is method implementation, I've highlighted the code that Leaks saids is leaking 100%

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) mutableDeepCopy {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToReturn = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self count]];
    NSArray *keys = [self allKeys];

    for(id key in keys) {
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];
        id copy = nil;
        if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableDeepCopy)]) {
            copy = [value mutableDeepCopy];
        } else if ([value respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)]) {
            copy = [value mutableCopy]; //This is the Leak
        }
        if (copy == nil) {
            copy = [value copy];
        }
        [dictionaryToReturn setValue:copy forKey:key];
    }
    return dictionaryToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but you should use objectForKey:/setObject:forKey: rather than valueForKey:/setValueForKey:  The latter are really designed for KVC and while they do almost the same thing on an NSDictionary, they do it more slowly and with subtle differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to analyse this in light of Apple's [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Starting with this line:

```
self.mutableDictionary = [self.immutableDictionary mutableDeepCopy];
```

I would expect mutableDeepCopy to return an object I own, so at some point I need to release or autorelease it. e.g.

```
NSMutableDeepCopy* temp = [self.immutableDictionary mutableDeepCopy];
self.mutableDictionary = temp;
[temp release];
```

or

```
self.mutableDictionary = [[self.immutableDictionary mutableDeepCopy] autorelease];
```

So now we need to look at mutableDeepCopy.  Because it has 'copy' in the name it needs to returned an "owned" object which, in practice means "forgetting" to release the returned object.  You have already failed to do that when you create the returned object in the first line, since dictionaryWithCapacity: gives you an object you do not own.  Replace it with

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryToReturn = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];
```

Now you own it.

It is important that you make your mutableDeepCopy obey the rules because it means you can treat the objects returned from mutableDeepCopy, mutableCopy and copy in exactly the same way.  In all three cases you own the object copy  that you insert into the array.  Because you own it, you must release it or it'll leak as you found out.  So, at the end of the loop, you need

```
[copy release];
```

That'll stop the leak.

Comment: Great explanation Jeremy. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

How is your property declared? If is is `retain` or `copy`, then this doesn't leak.

Your problem is that the name `mutableDeepCopy` suggests that it returns a retained object, and not an autoreleased one as it actually does.

**Edit:**
And at the mutableDeepCopy itself, you need to release the `copy` variable after adding to the dictionary.

Comment: Which property are you wondering about? Both Dictionaries have (nonatomic,retain) specified in the property

Comment: I meant the mutableDictionary property that you use in the second code block.

Answer (score 2):

`mutableCopy` increments the retain count of the object, as does `setValue:forKey:`. This means that when `dictionaryToReturn` is dealloc'ed, the object that had `mutableCopy` called still has a retain count of one.

Try doing this instead:

```
copy = [[value mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: That appears to work but now when I'm running Instruments the app crashes when I attempt to execute that code. However, I haven't seen any crashes when I'm just using the app.

Comment: Odd. Keep in mind (like Eiko mentions), methods with the word "copy" in the name should be returning an object with a retain count of +1. mutableCopy and copy already do, but your mutableDeepCopy method does not. Adjust the memory management of method variables and the returned object accordingly, and give it another shot.